# What happens to the CKSubscription(s), if someone deletes the app?

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6, cloudkit

If you subscribe for something, you'll get notified about changes. You create a `CKSubscription` for that. But what happens to this subscription, if you delete the app? Do I need to take care about it, or CloudKit do the job for me?

***For example:***

I created a subs for a specific user, so i'll get push notification and store the subs ID on my phone so as to delete it, when no longer needed. When I delete-thats fine-this means I don't want to get any not. any longer=and it deletes from server as well.

But when I delete the app, it does not delete from CloudKit AND I'm getting notification from this particular person although there is no information about him/her on my phone to delete its subs, since I re-install the app.

How should i accomplish that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

the subscriptions will remain active but notifications won't arrive at the user because the app is removed. All user data will also remain in CloudKit. So he could just reinstall the app and everything is as it was. There is no way to detect if a user has deleted your app.

Comment: Hi Edwin, I know we should subscribe the user once in a lifecycle of the app but if can't remove that subscription, how to check to not re-subscribe the user who removed the app and re-install it again. Because you will get duplicate notification if you subscribe more than once. Thanks

Comment: in CloudKit you cannot create the same subscription twice. If a user reinstalls the app and creates an identical subscription, then you will get a CloudKit error that it already exists. If you do want to check all subscriptions, then you can use the fetchAllSubscriptionsWithCompletionHandler and remove all subscriptions.

Comment: same here...after deleting the app and re-install it, the subs remains in the cloud, so if i subscribe again, duplicated notification are given. In this case, if i subscribe again, i'll get an error that subs are already exists. If i create a subscription for a specified user, who creates records in the public zone, do i have to save my subs to the public DB, or can i use my private? (hope you can see my point)

Comment: I thought you can not create subscriptions in the private database? And this would be pointless because you will not get notified for changes you made yourselves. And nobody else will write in the private database.

Comment: I think you can create subscriptions in a private database. And it makes sense in a case where you have multiple iOS devices with the same iCloud account logged in. Your other devices would receive notifications, thus updating records from the cloud.